# Set Generated Sigma Algebra Proof

Tags: measure-theory

I'm a BSc holder in math teaching myself measure theory. I'm using the Springer Text "Measure Theory & Probability Theory" by Athreya & Lahiri. I am on problem 1.7, and am having difficulty understanding the notation

[Here is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L601B.png)

Particularly, I am having difficulty understanding $$\cup_{\delta\in J} B_\delta, J \subset \{1,,,k\},$$ where $B_\delta = \cap^k_{i = 1}B_i(\delta_i)\\ \delta = \{0,1\}^k\\ B_i(0) = B_i^c,\; B_i(1) = B_i$

and $B = \{B_i\; | \; 1 \leq i \leq k \leq \infty\} \subset P(\Omega)$

The goal of the problem is to show that $\sigma\langle B \rangle = \{ E \; | \; E = \cup_{\delta \in J} B_\delta, J \subset \{1,,,k\}\}$

My main hangup is that I don't see how $\delta \in J$ can be, since $0 \notin J$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The notation in that text is not consistent. Reusing the $\delta$ for the name of a dummy variable would be ok, even if confusing, but what is not ok, is that dummy variable that takes values in $J$ to be the subscript of $B_\delta$. It should have been $E=\bigcup_{i\in J}B_{\delta^{(i)}}$, with $\delta^{(i)}\in\{0,1\}^k$.

Comment: @user85667 Thanks for the input! I’m unsure as to what specificity I am to put to the k, as well. I will work on updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $B$ is just a finite collection of subsets of $\Omega$. For convenience of notation, the elements of $B$ have been indexed: $B = \{B_i \mid 1 \le i \le k\}$, where each $B_i \subseteq \Omega$.
- $k$ is just the number of sets in $B$.
- Each $\delta$ is a sequence $\{\delta_i \mid i \le k\}$ with the requirement that each $\delta_i$ is either $0$ or $1$. Alternatively, you can think of $\delta$ has being an element of $\{0,1\}^k$ - effectively, a $k$-bit binary number.
- $B_i(0) = B_i$ and $B_i(1) = B_i^c$, the complement of $B_i$.
- For a given binary number $\delta$, define $B_\delta = \bigcap_{i=1}^k B_i(\delta_i)$. That is, $B_\delta$ is an intersection of $k$ sets, where for each index $i$, the set will either be $B_i$ or $B_i^c$. The bits of $\delta$ determine whether you get $B_i$ or its complement in the $i$-th slot.
- user85667 is correct that they screwed up the notation in their set for $\sigma\langle B \rangle$, but did not get the correct intent. What it should have been is $$\sigma\langle B \rangle = \left\{ \bigcup_{\delta \in J} B_\delta\ \middle |\ J \subseteq \{0,1\}^k\right\}$$

That is, the $B_\delta$ are intersections of the $k$ sets $B_i$ or their complements, and $\sigma\langle B\rangle$ is the set of all possible unions of sets of the various $B_\delta$.

---

Another way of stating this would be to first define $$\mathscr C = \left\{ \bigcap_{i=1}^k C_i\ \middle |\ C_i = B_i \text{ or } C_i = B_i^c, \text{ for }1 \le i \le k\right\}$$
Then $$\sigma\langle B \rangle = \left\{ \bigcup_{E \in \mathscr E} E \ \middle |\ \mathscr E \subseteq \mathscr C\right\}$$